# How to start a shell terminal session in Java and use it to put commands and read their results keeping the previous context

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a web application that has to mirror a Linux shell, that is to say, the users will have a screen that simulates the shell and will have an actual shell in the server side.

I have implemented a quick & dirty solution to test the interaction with the shell Process but it doesn't seem to work: this is a simple Spring Controller where the user passes commands and should get their results:

```
@RestController
public class ShController{

    @GetMapping("/sh")
    public DeferredResult<String> shSessionCommand(@RequestParam String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        DeferredResult<String> dr = new DeferredResult<>();

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh");
        //START SHELL
        Process p = pb.start();

        InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            //BACKGROUND SHELL OUTPUT READ
            byte[] read = new byte[2048];
            try {
                inputStream.read(read);
                dr.setResult(new String(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        //TO ALLOW THE SHELL READER TO START BEFORE PASSING THE COMMAND
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //WRITE THE USER COMMAND
        OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();

        return dr;
    }
}
```

When I call `/sh?command=ls` `outputStream.write(command.getBytes());` writes `ls` but `inputStream.read(read)` is blocked for ever. Why?

**UPDATE:**

Clarifications:

1. Every user needs to have its own shell Process
2. Every user shell session will be used for a long time to keep its context

I have updated the Controller to reflect this. There is a Map where I keep the relation between users and their shell Process. Now **I close the OutputStream and the `inputStream.read(read);` does read the command result, BUT, only the first time**. Subsequent calls to issue more commands throw `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` when invoking `outputStream.write(command.getBytes());`. Any ideas?

```
@RestController
public class ShController{

    private Map<String, Process> shellMap = new HashMap<>();

    @GetMapping("/sh")
    public DeferredResult<String> shSessionCommand(@RequestParam String command, HttpSession session) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        DeferredResult<String> dr = new DeferredResult<>();

        Process p = getUserShell(session.getId());

        InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("****THREAD");
            byte[] read = new byte[2048];
            try {
                inputStream.read(read);
                dr.setResult(new String(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        t.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("****COMMAND");
        OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        return dr;
    }

    private Process getUserShell(String user) throws IOException {
        if(this.shellMap.get(user) == null){
            System.out.println("****Creating process");
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh");
            Process process = pb.start();
            shellMap.put(user, process);
        }
        return shellMap.get(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Jsch library: https://gist.github.com/kdelfour/5f1fde64c3d23daea704 ?

Comment: I think I don't need to ssh into localhost since the webapp and the shell are on the same host...

Comment: closing shell input will terminate shell when it will call next read to get next line, which effect is to close output this is why java read is done

Comment: Right, so how can I read the shell output while issuing more commands to the same process?

Comment: maybe appending a keyword line at the end of each command output to indicate the command is terminated, and using readline until it reads this line, indeed the caller can't know how long command take, also because a command can return empty output, in a shell it's a subprocess which has been terminated but can't be seen from java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I wasn't sending the new line (enter) character, it's as if I never submitted the command. This is the solution:

```
@RestController
public class ShController{

    private Map<String, Process> shellMap = new HashMap<>();

    @GetMapping("/sh")
    public String shSessionCommand(@RequestParam String command, HttpSession session) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String result = "";
        Process process = getUserShell(session.getId());
        InputStream out = process.getInputStream();
        OutputStream in = process.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4000];
        boolean read = false;
        boolean written = false;
        while (!read) {
            int no = out.available();
            if (no > 0) {
                int n = out.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(no, buffer.length));
                result = new String(buffer, 0, n);
                read = true;
            }

            if(!written) {
                in.write((command + "\n").getBytes());
                in.flush();
                written = true;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private Process getUserShell(String user) throws IOException {
        if(this.shellMap.get(user) == null){
            System.out.println("****Creating process");
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-i");
            Process process = pb.start();
            shellMap.put(user, process);
        }
        return shellMap.get(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command sh runs a REPL interface that waits for input until closed with an **exit** command. With java.lang.process, you already have shell access, so I think you should deliver the $command to your java.lang.ProcessBuilder.

Mock-up of what I mean ->

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestCmd {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(args[0]).start();
        InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
        byte[] read = new byte[2048];
        inputStream.read(read);
        System.out.println(new String(read));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:
java TestCmd ls

- TestCmd.class
- TestCmd.java

Comment: The point is that I need to keep the context of the shell (Process). I mean if a user does "cd someDir" the next call should access that same shell process to go on working from "someDir". Also every user should have his own shell Process

Answer (score 0):

The read may be blocked waiting for more data while the io is not closed, it seems you are missing synchronization between two threads, in a shell except when launched in background `&` the caller waits for child termination and it's notified by the os through the sigchld.

Also using a sh process and parsing output will be unsafe and too complicated, to have an example just open two shells in two terminals:

```
# first terminal
mkfifo /tmp/fifo1
exec </tmp/fifo1


# second terminal
exec >/tmp/fifo1
echo 'ls /'
... other echo 'commands'
# to close and clean
exec >/dev/tty
rm /tmp/fifo1
```

you can see in first terminal echoing the prompt and the output are mixed without a safe way to distinguish the two.

Sorry the answer is not clear because I mixed shell and tty, following example will show that something is missing to indicate the end of output because stream is still open.

```
# first terminal
mkfifo /tmp/fifo1 /tmp/fifo2
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < /tmp/fifo2

# second terminal
# start a sh process in background reading from fifo1 and writing to fifo2
sh < /tmp/fifo1 > /tmp/fifo2 2>&1 &
# redirect current output to sh input
exec > /tmp/fifo1
echo 'ls /'

...
# to clean
# redirect current output to tty, also kill the sh because closing input
exec > /dev/tty
rm /tmp/fifo1 /tmp/fifo2
```